# I have 2 itemsControl highlight the selected items in one itemscontrol highlight corresponding items in another itemsControl

Tags: wpf

WPF I have 2 itemsControl one is DataGrid and another is ListView.when items in one of them is selected the corresponding items in other itemsControl should be selected and highlight,and vice versa.Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply bind the `SelectedItem` for one control to the `SelectedItem` of the other

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ... />

<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=MyListView, Path=SelectedItem}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel!!!It's great when I try it,but another question occur to me is that when I choose multiple rows,only the first selected row will affected another ItemsControl's corresponding item,while the rest of rows will have no impact to another ItemsControl's corresponding items.

Comment: @user1039858 Bind `SelectedItems` instead of `SelectedItem` to allow for multiple selected items

Comment: Well,I do try to Bind SelectedItems but it's a readonly property.When I try it,the application will crush!!